# Stomp not sending the messages recieved from client

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, websocket, sockjs, stompjs

i m facing a problem with the integration of stompjs and spring boot app .I tried a code unfortunately does not work i did not the reason .Actually the client fill a form and after submitting he sent the number of order to the other connected users via sockJS. This is the code please give me some advises to make it work :

```js
$('#btn-save').on('click', function (e) {
 
 
   sendForm();
});

var ws;
var stompClient;






ws=new SockJS("/formordre");

stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);


stompClient.connect({},function(frame){
 
stompClient.subscribe("/topic/formordre",function(message){
console.log("Received:" + message) ;
toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": true,
    "debug": false,
    "newestOnTop": false,
    "progressBar": false,
    "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
    "preventDuplicates": false,
    "onclick": null,
    "showDuration": "300",
    "hideDuration": "1000",
    "timeOut": "0",
    "extendedTimeOut": "0",
    "showEasing": "swing",
    "hideEasing": "linear",
    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
  }

toastr.info( message.body);


});
},function(error){
 console.log("Stomp protocol error "+ error);
});
 
});


function sendForm(){
 
 stompClient.send("/topic/formordre",{},$('#num_ord').val());
};
```

```css
package com.example.dot.web;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketBrokerConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
 registry.addEndpoint("/formordre").withSockJS();

} 
 
@Override
 public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

 registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
 .enableSimpleBroker("/topic","/queue");
 }


}
```

```html
package com.example.dot.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

 @Override
 public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addHandler(new QuestionHandler(), "/formordre").withSockJS();

 }

 class QuestionHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

  private List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {

   sessions.add(session);

  }

  @Override
  protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {

  
   
   for (WebSocketSession s : sessions) {
    try {
     s.sendMessage(message);
    } catch (IOException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

  }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it the declaration of ws and stompClient variables  must be at the top of the script . But when i submit the form , the message sent mutilple time , i don't  know the reason any one had idea !!!!